# How to define usercontrol in a page in xaml in windows 8, and reuse it in the same page?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

i want to use a usercontrol, (set of TextBlock & Combobox). I want 3 instance of it in the same, page. So how can I define such usercontrol in the same page's xaml? need to use page resource? or anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within Visual Studio you can define UserControls by going to Project --> Add New Item and selecting User Control. After defining it there you can then add a reference to it in the XAML of the page you want to use it in. You do this by adding a something along the lines of the following to the root tag of your page.

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage
    ...
    xmlns:CustomControlName="using:CustomControlNamespace"
    ...>
```

If you have to do it in the same XAML document, I guess you could define the control in the pages resources

```
<Page.Resources>

    <UserControl x:Name="CustomControl">
       ...
    </UserControl>

</Page.Resources>
```

Personally I would define a UserControl in a separate file. It separates things out and Visual Studio also gives you some basics to work from.

Comment: yes, but now 1 more problem is that, there i need to handle 3 different event for selection changed. how to identify then which combo generated the event? also, there need to be different path for binding, say for combo1, path="searchOption" for combo2, path="sortOption". How to achieve that?

Comment: after you have defined your custom control, you can make multiple instances of it (in the same way you might instantiate multiple button controls on your page). You can then assign each on of these a different name. To achieve the effect you've described I believe you will need to expose dependency properties for the combobox in your usercontrol. I'm not too experienced at doing this so you may need to search around for help with that, try searching "dependency property for user control combobox" or similar.

Comment: <stackpanel><textblock/><combobox /></stackpanel>
this is how my control looks like. as combobox is a child component, how would be possible for setting different binding-path and different handlers to combo for different instance of 'stackpanel'?

Comment: like I said, look in to dependency properties, they will allow you to do this. What you will do is expose the selected item/selected index property of the combobox of your usercontrol. Then when you have an instance you will be able to access each usercontrols combobox item individually. Look at these two pages for a general guide:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39077/Binding-to-ComboBox-SelectedItem-through-a-custom
and
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/034a35b1-8311-4492-b9a2-3296de694800